# unable to reduce space between table rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on an app where I have a table with rows and columns and a container of checkboxes in the format of the image below :

[image]

The problem is that I want the letters A , B , C , D which represent each row to align on the same height with my checkboxes and by reducing margin or padding between the letters I see no difference so I need your help

My code :

```css
.checkboxes-container{
  position: absolute;
  width:620px;
  height:240px;
  left:25%;
  top:42%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; 
}

.checkbox-container{
  background-color:teal;
  width:230px;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}


.checkbox-container div{
  flex-basis:100%;
}



.business-bx{
  margin-top:17px;
  transform:scale(1.5);  
}

.business-bx:not(:first-child){
  margin-left:38px;
}

.business-bx:first-child{
  margin-left:10px;
}


.table tbody tr td:first-child {
  font-weight:bold;
}

.table {
  border-spacing: 3em;
}


.letter{
  font-size:20px;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>


      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="letter">
        <td>A</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="letter">
        <td>B</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="letter">
        <td>C</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="letter">
        <td>D</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="checkboxes-container">
  <div class="checkbox-container business-boxes">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
      <input type="checkbox" class="business-bx">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a single table that included the inputs?...that would be logical to construct this

Comment: You are using a `<table>` for 1,2,3,4,A,B,C,D and a succession of `<div>` for the checkboxes. Have you consider using only one table?

Comment: @Paulie_D  I didn't know how to put checkboxes as table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by merging you checkbox code with the table. Here, I have updated the code.

```css
tbody>tr>td:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: teal;
    padding:20px;
}
tbody>tr>td{
    padding-right:5px;
}
thead>tr>td{
    text-align: center;
}
table{border-collapse: collapse;}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="letter">
                <td>A</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="letter">
                <td>B</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="letter">
                <td>C</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="letter">
                <td>D</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="business-bx"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why this answer his question?

Comment: He needs to align the checkbox with the rows so we can merge the checkbox code with the table which will result the same. Could you explain why this doesn't answer?

Comment: This answers the question, but is it easily understandable? About code only answer : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality

Comment: I have updated the comment is that understandable or more clarification is required.